# Visual Studio - find certain logic

Tags: visual-studio

I have to search in the whole code base for logic of the form:

```
while(...)
{
    try {
        ...
    } catch(...) {
        logger.Log(...)
    }
}
```

to check all occurrences, because this logic causes the disk to run full quickly if the error in the try catch block is unrecoverable and does not affect the loop condition.

Is there any way to do so, apart from a tedious manual search through all the zillion occurrences of try or while or logger.Log? Maybe a regular expression search?

Comment: I would suggest you use a Regex search, since this might be the quickest solution. Are you planning to write a small code spike / project to search through code. If that is the case, are you able to use the search facilities in Notepad++, or perhaps a free Grep tool?

Comment: Yes, I also have Notepad++ at hands.